# Series Capacitor impedance

Tags: electrical-resistance, capacitance

A series capacitor, for example, has infinite impedance at f=0 Hz
Is this statement true? If Yes then what is the reason!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

If you are talking about only capacitive AC circuits then we can say the following.

Answer (score 1):

Apply a steady voltage, $f = 0$, to the ends of a pair of parallel plates separated by a perfect insulator and wait for a period of time until the voltage across the capacitor is equal to the voltage of the supply and the current does not charge.
The value of that unchanging current will be zero and so the impedance of the capacitor, $\frac V I$,  is infinite.
Now change the voltage and a current will flow to and from the charged plates so now with a changing voltage the impedance is no longer infinite.